# Dynamically added controls not displaying in wpf page

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, revit-api

I am trying to build a Revit plugin using WPF and I am trying to add controls to a window dynamically. However, these controls are not getting displayed in the window and there is no error. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Xaml

```
    <ScrollViewer Margin="0,190,-0.4,-1">
        <StackPanel Name="TaskList" Height="auto" Width="auto">
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

c#

```
    for (var i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.Height = 100;
        canvas.Width = 300;
        canvas.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        canvas.Margin = new Thickness(20);

        System.Windows.Controls.TextBox tb = new System.Windows.Controls.TextBox();
        tb.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        tb.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        tb.Width = 300;
        tb.FontSize = 30;
        tb.Height = 100;
        tb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        tb.MaxLength = 40;
        tb.Text = dt.Rows[i][2].ToString();

        canvas.Children.Add(tb);
        TaskList.Children.Add(canvas);
        TaskList.UpdateLayout();
    }
```

**EDIT**
I am using a page tag as the base not window. Maybe that changes how i should approach the problem?

Comment: All the answers proposed here for other people are good solutions for my point of view and it is quite strange you can't get any display result yet. Could you please try to 1) remove any `ScrollViewer` margin. 2) Debug your `for` cycle to ensure you loop within it as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Canvas` entirely. You can add the `TextBox` elements to the `StackPanel` (`TaskList`) directly. If you want a border or spacing then you should use the `Border` control, not `Canvas`.

Additionally, only call `UpdateLayout()` **after** you've added all the controls to it:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

...

    for (var i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.Background   = new SolidColorBrush( Colors.Black );
        tb.Foreground   = new SolidColorBrush( Colors.White );
        tb.Width        = 300;
        tb.FontSize     =  30;
        tb.Height       = 100;
        tb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        tb.MaxLength    =  40;
        tb.Text         = dt.Rows[i][2].ToString();

        this.TaskList.Children.Add( tb );
    }

    this.TaskList.UpdateLayout();
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I tried your way but unfortunately, the controls are still not getting displayed in the window. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an ItemsControl, instead of creating UI elements in code behind:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="TaskList">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Width="300" Height="100" FontSize="30"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Then just add strings to its Items property:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    TaskList.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i][2].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this way but the controls are still not getting displayed, unfortunately. Any other ideas?

Comment: There is not enough detail in your question. Did you debug your code to see if there are any rows at all?

Comment: yup, I did. There are three rows in the dt. the for loop is moving as expected. The code control goes over the add without any problems but the items are just not getting displayed for some unknown reason. There is no error that is being displayed. Just let me know what more info you need and i will be happy to provide.

Comment: Is anything displayed at all? What if you set the ScrollViewer's Background, e.g. to Red? What if you don't use a ScrollViewer at all? What's the reason behind the ScrollViewer's Margin? Shouldn't there be a proper layout instead of large margins?

Comment: All the controls in the window are getting displayed. Only the controls that i am adding through code are not getting displayed. Can this be a problem with Revit API? I am using the IDockablePaneProvider interface to create a dockable window. Does that cause any problems for dynamic controls? I sort of need the scrollviewer since there can be n number of textboxes in the stackpanel. The scrollviewer has a mrgin because i dont want the entire window to be scrollable just a part of it. So the scrollviewer is placed in the bottom half of the page.

Comment: Not sure what that means. Is the ScrollViewer visible or not?

Comment: It is. the scrollviewer is visible. Just the textboxes that i am adding from code behind is not getting displayed.

Comment: It is. the scrollviewer is visible. Just the textboxes that i am adding from code behind is not getting displayed.